# error on uploading image to s3 while using onchange function angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

i am using a file input in my signup form .. when the submit button is clicked the user is added to the database and the fileupload begins.

in my html form i'm using onchange function but whenever the file is changed, console gives an error that the function is not defined

controller:

```
var vm = this;

$scope.setFile = function(element) {
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.theFile = element.files[0];
    console.log($scope.theFile)
});
}

$scope.signup = function () {
   $http
      .post('/api/usersignup', vm.userData)
      .then(function (data) {

  if (data) {
    uploadImage(data.userId, $scope.theFile)
  }
  else {
    console.log("null");
  }
})

};

function uploadImage(userId, fileData) {
console.log('user----------->'+userId+"------------------>"+fileData)
$http
.post('/api/testupload', userId, fileData)
.then(function (data) {


})
}
```

api for user signup

```
api.post('/usersignup', function(req, res) {

var name  = req.body.name,
email  = req.body.email,
password  = req.body.password;

var newUser = new User({
name: name,
email: email,
password: password,
tag: 'user'
});

 nev.createTempUser(newUser, function(err, newTempUser) {
    if (err) {
       return res.status(404).send(err);
 }

      // new user created
      if (newTempUser) {
        var URL = newTempUser[nev.options.URLFieldName];


        nev.sendVerificationEmail(email, URL, function(err, info) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(404).send(err);

          }
          res.json({
            msg: 'An email has been sent to you. Please check it to verify your account.',
            info: info
          });
        });

      // user already exists in temporary collection!
    } else {
      res.json({

        msg: 'You have already signed up. Please check your email to verify your account.'
      });
    }
  });   
});
```

api for image upload to s3

```
api.post('/testupload', function(req , res) {
userId = req.body.userId;
async.waterfall([
  function(done) {
    crypto.randomBytes(50, function(err, buf) {
      var photoid = buf.toString('hex') + '.png';
      done(err, photoid);
    });
  },

  function(photoid, done) {
    var file = req.body.fileData;
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);


    return s3fsImpl.writeFile(photoid, stream).then(function(err){
      fs.unlink(file.path, function(err){
        if(err)
          console.log(err);
      })
      var imgid = photoid;
      res.json(photoid);
    })
  }

  ])
});
```

the html code is here :

```
 <div class="container" ng-controller="UserCreateController as user">
<form  class="form-sigin" method="post" ng-submit="signup()" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.userData.name">
    email: <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.userData.email">
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.userData.password">
    <input  type="file" name="file" onChange="setFile(this)">                      
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" >Signup</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [*ngChange*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive doesn't support *input* type file (as you can check [**here**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1375)), yes, you have to use onchange, however, to call `onchange` you must change **this**:

```
<input  type="file" name="file" onChange="setFile(this)">
```

**for:**

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this)">
```

Comment: i did this, it worked.... but how to send this file now to the api call: 'testupload' ???

Comment: Well, you already the value of file, right? `$scope.theFile = element.files[0];`

Comment: okay, so i send $scope.theFIle to testupload..... but how to access it? req.body.theFile is undefined

Comment: What does `req` means? Also, how are you calling your `$http.post`?

Comment: inside signup---> uploadImage(data._id, $scope.theFile),      uploadimage:    $http
    .post('/api/testupload', userId, fileData)

Comment: see edited controller in question... i've added the upload function

Comment: Well, you're using `$scope` and at the same time, *controller as Syntax* and  what `console.log('user----------->'+userId+"------------------>"+fileData)` prints?

Comment: it prints: user----->undefined-------->undefined.

Comment: you could hep us... we're new to this... how to pass data through $http.post? text as well as file?

Comment: Below this line `.post('/api/usersignup', vm.userData).then(function (data) {` put a `console.log(data);`

Comment: Well, we're on the way to another question.. can you consider this answer to your **original** question that was related to how make **onchange** event work? And also feel free to make **another** post about how to post or something else, I'll be happy to answer it.